# Default repeater list does not show correct order of latest updated records with multiple document types

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I am using Kentico default repeater to show the latest updated documents. I have selected all document types (eg. article, page, etc.) which I want to show in a repeater as a list. I also want to show the list content based on the visitor's role and permissions so I would like to enable check permissions check box in repeater properties.

So now I except the records which are allowed to a user to show according to his/her role permission. I have created a role `Member` and have assigned member role to two documents A and B.

The result is not coming as I expect. When I login with member role, the latest updated document should come in the list from any document type which I have selected `ordered by modified date in reverse chronological order`.

But I am getting only records from first document type which is selected in the list.

> e.g. if I select articles and page then I see only documents of the type article only. If I select page first then I see only page type documents in the list. Document of the other types are not shown at all.

Please suggest where we need to modify in the settings if any change is required?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like your specific issue but when using multiple document types in a single repeater, make sure that the field names match up.  For example, if you want to sort on a date field, it needs to be named the same in both document types.

Also, another related one, make sure that you're distinguishing between the "core date field" that Kentico keeps track of, and any other date field you might have.  For example, every document has a "date last modified" field, while a news document might have an additional "Post date" field or something similar.

If all else fails, you might want to try is to hotfix the site.  This could be a bug in the version you're using.  You can find hotfixes for Kentico here: http://devnet.kentico.com/Bugtracker/Hotfixes.aspx